# How can I interact directly with Oracle's Instant Client via Powershell on OSX?

Tags: oracle, macos, powershell, mono, powershell-core

I wrote a [PowerShell module](https://github.com/craibuc/PsOracle) to interact with an Oracle database, in the same manner that `Invoke-SqlCmd` works with SQL Server.

I'd like to be able to use this module on OS X, now that Window's [PowerShell](https://github.com/powershell/powershell) is available.

In Windows, the `System.Data.OracleClient` assembly provides the Oracle calls.  While there is a [Mono version](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/database-access/providers/oracle/), it appears that OS X support is `TODO`.

Is there a way to interact directly with Oracle's [Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html) via PowerShell and avoid the assembly issue?

Comment: Doesn't look like it as they haven't implemented it.